# On refresh dropdown data gets changed in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have added a dropdown list in my application. it is working as expected but while I am refreshing the page, dropdown data gets changed.But I want that selected value only.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.initialState={
      id:'1',
      layers: [
                { id: "1", layer: "A" },
                { id: "2", layer: "B" },
                { id: "3", layer: "C" },
                { id: "4", layer: "D" },
                { id: "5", layer: "E" },
                { id: "6", layer: "F" }
              ],
      defaultLayer:'A',
     showField:false
    }
    this.state = this.initialState
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.CheckLayers= this.CheckLayers.bind(this)
   }

CheckLayers(evt){
    if(evt.target.value === '5'){
        this.setState({showField:true})
    }
    let selectedLayer = this.state.layers
                            .find(layer => layer.id === evt.target.value);

    this.setState({
                    projectId:evt.target.value,
                    defaultLayer:selectedLayer.layer});

    }
    handleChange(evt) {
    this.setState({[evt.target.name]: evt.target.value}
        )};


    handleSubmit(evt) {

     if(null == this.state.id){
        this.state.projectId=this.initialState.id
    }

 let selectedLayer = this.state.layers
                            .find(layer => layer.id === this.state.id);
     this.state.defaultLayer = selectedLayer.layer
  }

render(){
    return (
        <div>
        <form  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
             Layer:
            <select name="id" onChange={this.CheckLayers}>
            {this.state.layers.map(item => (
                          <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                            {item.layer}
                          </option>
                        ))}
            </select>
           { this.state.showField && <input type="text" name="id" value= {this.state.id} 
style={{display:'block'}} onChange={this.handleChange}/>}
            </label>
  <button type="button"  class ="button" value="detail"  onClick= 
  {this.handleSubmit}>Detail</button>
  </form></div>}}}
```

here if user select 6 i.e on dropdown it will show 'F' but on refresh it will show 'A' only.Please advice!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Redux with redux-persist or you can use browser's localStorage as a quick solution. Change your component as

```
this.initialState={
  id:'1',
  layers: [
            { id: "1", layer: "A" },
            { id: "2", layer: "B" },
            { id: "3", layer: "C" },
            { id: "4", layer: "D" },
            { id: "5", layer: "E" },
            { id: "6", layer: "F" }
          ],
  defaultLayer:localStorage.getItem('defaultLayer') ? localStorage.getItem('defaultLayer') : 'A',
 showField:false
}
```

And in your handler

```
handleChange(evt) {
this.setState({[evt.target.name]: evt.target.value})
localStorage.setItem('defaultLayer', evt.target.name);
};
```

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page your components get unmounted and re-mounted again and will be intialised again with the intialState(defaultLayer:'A'). Hence the same you see. If you want to persist across refresh or across user sessions you can use something like localStorage to save interested value in it. Then in the initialState you can check if there is something in localStorage use it else assign defaultLayer: 'A'.

Just to give you an idea. Do this in you initialState:
`defaultLayer: localStorage.get('selectedDropdown')`

And inside of your dropdownChange handler set this as:
`localStorage.set('selectedDropdown', 'whatever')`

Comment: I did that and I am getting the proper value for it. Let's say if user chooses 'C', then in local storage it will be set as 3 but in the front end on refresh, I will get 'A' only. Localstorage sets the id properly but in front end it shows wrong option

Comment: Could you post some code that explains what you have done with localStorage. Show me your initialState and onDropdownChange handlers.

Comment: on handleSumit(evt)                                                                                                          
    sessionStorage.setItem('selLayer',selectedLayer.layer); and in componentDidMount (),i am retrieving it componentDidMount() {
      const layer = sessionStorage.getItem('selLayer')

Comment: You need to set the state after getting the layer or move this getItem logic to intialState to your constructor. Hope this helps.